# Discrete math combinatorial proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Prove that for every positive integer n,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{\frac{n-l}{2}}\binom{n}{l}\binom{n-l}{r}\binom{n-l-r}{r}$$

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$ but I can't seem to find a way to connect it to the right side. Any help would be appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: Prove by induction? Try induction

Comment: There is a hint that says, "You probably want to prove this combinatorially: the left side can be thought of as enumerating pairs of subsets of {1,2,...,n} with a particular property. Can you characterize each pair in other ways, and count those characterizations?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: The lefthand side is the number of pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $|A|=|B|$. You can classify these pairs according to the number of elements that they have in common. Suppose that $C=A\cap B$; then $A\setminus C$ and $B\setminus C$ must be disjoint subsets of $[n]$. Think of setting $\ell=|C|$ and $r=|A\setminus C|=|A\setminus B|$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry for my stupidity but what does A \ C and B \ C mean?

Comment: @Kelsey: Set difference: $A\setminus C$ is the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $C$. You may be more familiar with the older notation $A-C$.

Comment: So when it says n choose k squared, its saying choose k elements for A and k elements for B?

Comment: @Kelsey: That’s one possible combinatorial interpretation of the product $\binom{n}k^2$: if we decide that $A$ and $B$ are to have cardinality $k$, there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose the set $A$, and no matter what set $A$ is chosen, there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose $B$, so there are $\binom{n}k^2$ ways to choose the ordered pair $\langle A,B\rangle$.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much. You are truly a lifesaver!

Comment: @Kelsey: You’re welcome!